# SGD classifier Precision-Recall curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall, stochastic-gradient

I'm working on a binary classification problem and I have an sgd classifier like so:

```
sgd = SGDClassifier(
    max_iter            = 1000, 
    tol                 = 1e-3,
    validation_fraction = 0.2,
    class_weight = {0:0.5, 1:8.99}
)
```

I fitted it on my training set and plotted the precision-recall curve:

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_precision_recall_curve
disp = plot_precision_recall_curve(sgd, X_test, y_test)
```

[image]

Given that the sgd classifier in scikit-learn uses `loss="hinge"` by default, how is it possible for this curve to be plotted? My understanding is that the output of the sgd is not probabilistic -- it's either 1/0. So there are no "thresholds", and yet the sklearn precision-recall curve plots a zigzagged graph with different kinds of thresholds. What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The situation you describe is practically identical with one found in a [documentation example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-precision-recall-py), using the first 2 classes of the iris data and a LinearSVC classifier (the algorithm uses the squared hinge loss, which, like the hinge loss you use here, results in a classifier that produces only binary outcomes and not probabilistic ones). The resulting plot there is:

[image]

i.e. qualitatively similar to yours here.

Nevertheless, your question is a legitimate one and a nice catch indeed; how comes and we get a behavior similar to one produced by probabilistic classifiers, when our classifier does not indeed produce probabilistic predictions (and hence any notion of a threshold sounds irrelevant)?

To see why this is so, we need to do some digging into the scikit-learn source code, starting from the `plot_precision_recall_curve` function used here and following the thread down into the rabbit hole...

Starting from the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460/sklearn/metrics/_plot/precision_recall_curve.py#L205) of `plot_precision_recall_curve`, we find:

```
y_pred, pos_label = _get_response(
    X, estimator, response_method, pos_label=pos_label)
```

So, for the purposes of plotting the PR curve, the predictions `y_pred` are **not** produced directly by the `predict` method of our classifier, but by the `_get_response()` internal function of scikit-learn.

[`_get_response()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460dbf19e5e196b8ef48f9712b72a3b3c3/sklearn/metrics/_plot/base.py#L88) in turn includes the lines:

```
prediction_method = _check_classifier_response_method(
    estimator, response_method)

y_pred = prediction_method(X)
```

which finally leads us to the `_check_classifier_response_method()` internal function; you can check the full [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460dbf19e5e196b8ef48f9712b72a3b3c3/sklearn/metrics/_plot/base.py#L6) of it - what is of interest here are the following [3 lines](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460dbf19e5e196b8ef48f9712b72a3b3c3/sklearn/metrics/_plot/base.py#L36) after the `else` statement:

```
predict_proba = getattr(estimator, 'predict_proba', None)
decision_function = getattr(estimator, 'decision_function', None)
prediction_method = predict_proba or decision_function
```

By now, you may have started getting the point: under the hood, `plot_precision_recall_curve` checks if either a `predict_proba()` or a `decision_function()` method is available for the classifier used; and if a `predict_proba()` is *not* available, like your case here of an SGDClassifier with hinge loss (or the [documentation example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-precision-recall-py) of a LinearSVC classifier with squared hinge loss), it reverts to the `decision_function()` method instead, in order to calculate the `y_pred` which will be subsequently used for plotting the PR (and ROC) curve.

---

The above have arguably answered your *programming* question about how exactly scikit-learn produces the plot and the underlying calculations in such cases; further theoretical inquiries regarding if & why using the `decision_function()` of a non-probabilistic classifier is indeed a correct and legitimate approach to get a PR (or ROC) curve are out of scope for SO, and they should be addressed to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), if necessary.

Comment: @nz_21 you are welcome; it was a legitimate question indeed (not typical in SO nowadays), and I am surprised it had not been asked before (I searched for possible duplicates before answering, but could not find any).

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted. I think people don't dig much into sklearn nowadays, so it is kinda normal it hasn't been asked before.